# Getting a signal SIGABRT when using instantiateViewController with UIVewController

Tags: ios, swift

I hope someone can help me with this problem I am getting with swift.

I am trying to add an array of `UIViewController`s to a `UIPageViewController`. However, whenever I try to access a view controller through the method `instantiateViewController`, I get a SIGABRT error.

```
let vc: UIViewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: views[index]) as! UIPageViewController
```

Here is my entire ViewController.swift file just for the reference.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var pageViewController: UIPageViewController!
    var views: [String] = ["view1","view2"]

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.pageViewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "pageViewController") as! UIPageViewController

        var arr: [UIViewController] = []

        for i in 0..<views.count{

            arr.append(assignView(index: i))

        }

        self.pageViewController.setViewControllers(arr, direction: .forward, animated: true, completion: nil )

        self.addChildViewController(self.pageViewController)
        self.view.addSubview(self.pageViewController.view)
        pageViewController.didMove(toParentViewController: self)

    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    func assignView (index: Int) -> UIViewController{

        let vc: UIViewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: views[index]) as! UIPageViewController

        return vc

    }


}
```

Can someone tell me why my code is throwing me this error?

Thank you so much!

Comment: would you paste the error completely? Bare in mind the console will always try to provide meaningful messages back to you... so you can debug easier

Comment: Have you assigned your viewController identifiers correctly?

Answer (score 0):

From the line below:
self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "pageViewController") as! UIPageViewController

It seems that storyboard is treated as optional. It may be that the storyboard variable is getting nil when you are trying to access it.Ideally it should not be nil and should not be optional. 
If the optional is purposefully done then you can apply a "if let" to check before you access.

Let me know if you need further clarification.

Comment: It is not done on purpose. So how should I deal with it? I have tried using a ! instead of a ? but it still doesn't work. Do you know how I may make the storyboard not nil?

Answer (score 0):

SIGABRT is a controlled crash and the app terminated mostly on purpose. It mostly resulted from programmer's fault.

Look for following as there is two possible causes to crash.

1. self.storyboard doesn't properly got initialised as there is no corresponding storyboard or incorrectly referred.
2. View controller's identifier is incorrectly referred.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following example

`var mainView: UIStoryboard!
mainView = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
let samplecontroller : UIViewController = mainView.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "iPhone")`

In the above example mainView is my instance referring to StoryBoard which is implicitly unwrapped(this is done on purpose to specify that this cannot be nil)
samplecontroller is the instance of the scene in the storyBoard. "iPhone" is the name of the StoryBoardID of the scene.

This snippet will ensure that the mainView will never be nil provided my storyboard is setup correctly with the Ids and names used.

After this you can still have a safety check like

`if let test = mainView {
//Do your stuff
}`

Let me know if this helps.